# Loop executing infinitely in singly Linked List Node creation

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
struct SinglyLinkedListNode{
    int data; 
    SinglyLinkedListNode* next = NULL;
};

SinglyLinkedListNode* init(int data){
    SinglyLinkedListNode *newNode =  (SinglyLinkedListNode*)malloc(sizeof(SinglyLinkedListNode));
    newNode -> data = data;
    
**Line 1**
    newNode -> next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}
```

If I do not specify the `next` of new `Node` as `NULL` then my loop is running for infinite time. Why is that so?

Isn't `next` automatically set to `NULL` when I create a new `Node`:

```
SinglyLinkedListNode *newNode = init(5);
```

Comment: Default value of buffer allocated via `malloc()` and not initialized is indeterminate.

Comment: Also, `malloc` doesn't create any object. While it might work, it is Undefined Behaviour, because no constructor is called. A call to `malloc` should be followed by a call to placement `new` (or replaced with a direct call to `new`).

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, whenever you need to use C-style casting (like you do with `(SinglyLinkedListNode*)malloc(...)`) you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong. Use `new` in C++.

Comment: Also, `NULL` is an old C-compatibility macro. Inn C++ use `nullptr` for null pointers. Or `0` if you're using a very old compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The memory allocated by `malloc()` is not initialized.  If you don't initialize the `newNode->next` field, its value will be indeterminate, which will causes problems for your linked list.